# How to determine if a URI is escaped?

Tags: uri, apache-commons-httpclient

I am using apache commons HTTPClient to download web resources. The URI for these resources come from third parties, I do not generate them.

The commons httpclient requires a URI object to be given to the GetMethod object.

The URI constructor takes a string (for the uri) and a boolean specifying if it is escaped or not.

Currently, I am doing the following to determine if the original url I am given is already escaped...

```
    boolean isEscaped = URIUtil.getPathQuery(originalUrl).contains("%");

    m.setURI(new URI(originalUrl, isEscaped));
```

Is this the correct way to determine if a uri is already escaped?

Update...

according to wikipedia ( Well, according to wikipedia ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding ) it says that percent is a reserved character and should always be encoded... I am quoting verbatim here...

> Percent-encoding the percent character[edit] Because the percent ("%")
>   character serves as the indicator for percent-encoded octets, it must
>   be percent-encoded as "%25" for that octet to be used as data within a
>   URI.

Doesnt this mean that you can never have a naked '%' character in a valid uri?

Also, the uri(s) come from various sources so I cannot be sure if they are escaped or unescaped.

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't work. It's possible the un-encoded string has a `%` in it already.

ex:
https://www.google.com/#q=like%25&safe=off
is the url for a google search for `like%`. In unescaped form it would be https://www.google.com/#q=like%&safe=off

Your consumers should let you know if the URI is escaped or not.

Comment: `It's possible the un-encoded string has a % in it already.` Then couldn't you just use regex or something to determine if the `%` is being used for encoding vs a literal string?

Comment: no because what if the user is legitimately looking up `%25`? you can't just assume that `%25` is an encoded `%` it could be it's own string.

Comment: Well, according to wikipedia ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding ) it says that percent is a reserved character and should always be encoded...